# Get position of a image inside view cell listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with view cell.Inside the listview I have a image( using absolute layout with ratio) which i use for some animation.To do animation I need the x and y coordinates. I am extending the image as

```cs
class MyImage : Image
{
   public void AnimateImage(double value)
   {
      this.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(this.X, this.Y - (value), 20, value), 
   }
}
```

I need to get the x and y coordinates during the time of loading(not by using any events).Through this code am not getting the correct x,y coordinates. Value am getting with the help of bindable property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by `Through this code am not getting the correct x,y coordinates.`? What is wrong?

I use you code and it works on my side.

I create a ListView with image in ViewCell and is a layout by absolute layout:

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listView" RowHeight="200">

        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,500,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional" Padding="5,0,0,0">

                        <local:MyImage Source="Images"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,1,.1,.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And in the code behind, i use you code and the animation works well:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyImage : Image{

    public MyImage() {

        NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(3, true,  (obj) =>
        {
            AnimateImage(30);
        });
    }

    public void AnimateImage(double value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.X);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Y);

        this.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(this.X, this.Y - (value), 20, value), 500);
    }
}
```

The Y of image reduce 50 every 3 seconds and the height of image change to 50.

Am I doing something different with you?

Here is a gif:

[image: gif]

**Update:**

Add a little delay before call the animation as I mentioned in my comment:

```
public MyImage() {

    Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(t => AnimateImage(30));

}
```

Comment: The first time this.X = 0 and this.Z = 0 . Is it expected behaviour? My code is the same as yours, except that am not using a timer.

Comment: @George Yes, if you call `AnimateImage` in the `MyImage()`  directly, you will get X=0 and Y = 0, because MyImage() is `Constructor` and in this method, it is creating the imageView and this imageView has not been added to the superView yet at that time, so the imageView does not have x,y, width,height at that time. Add a little delay on your side would solve this problem. The delay is use to waiting the image to be added to the superView. See my edited answer. If the answer solved your problem and you can accept/upvote it.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work with the help of delay is this.X= 0